# I can not assign value in the standard ITEM field in a sublist

Tags: netsuite

I can not assign value in the standard ITEM field in a sublist. 
I do the getValue, the id of the list is captured, but when I do the setValue the item does not appear in the list. I did the same process with dozens of fields and only this did not work. In the log file it shows that the id has been fetched, but it is still not allocated

It is a process of generating a sales invoice. When the user clicks on the purchase order, the invoice is displayed, and this data must be replicated.

```
var numLines = order.getLineCount({
      sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_xxxyyyyxx"
    });

if (numLines) {
      for (var i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {  



    var item = order.getSublistValue({
         sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_xxxyyyyxx",
         fieldId: "custrecord_itemFieldId",
         line: i
         });


    newRecord.insertLine({
        sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_xxxyyyyxx",
        line: i
        });


   newRecord.setSublistValue({
      sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_xxxyyyyxx",
      fieldId: "custrecorditemFildId",
      line: i
      value: item
      });
  }
```

Comment: What is the context of this script? UserEvent? Client? Suitelet?  What stage?

Comment: Blanck Script, Sript_ScriptName.js  About the stage, what I can explain is: I have a screen in which the data of a sales order, or purchase order, is displayed. When you click the button the process runs, and another screen with the generated invoice data appears.